# Confide login view

Tags: laravel

I’m using Confide (laravel package) for the authentication of our users on our website.

I have two different links on our website, each requiring the user to login before showing content. On the login screen, I need to show two different messages depending on which link was clicked on.

What is the best way to do this? I'd rather not edit any of the confide code, so I thought I could create two different views which could include the Confide login view, and each display a different message, but I'm not sure if that is the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the message in a session variable and then display it on the login screen.

[`Session::flash`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#flash-data) is especially suited for such a situation. It makes the variable available for the *next request* and then deletes it.

```
Session::flash('message', 'Please login to see this content');
```

And then in the login view

```
@if(Session::has('message')
    <p>{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
@endif
```

This way you can set `message` to everything you want and it will be displayed on the login page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I edit the login screen (stored in app/views/users), will confide override my login screen when I update the confide package? Or should I store the login screen somewhere else so that confide won't override the screen when I update the package?

Comment: I haven't used the package but I suppose you created the view files by running `php artisan view:publish`? Because the actual view files of the package are stored in the vendor directory

Comment: Thanks, again it works (apologies for the late comment). In order to keep the variable for the next request, I had to do a reflash {{ Session::reflash(‘message’)}} just after {{ Session::get('message') }}.

Comment: That's right. If you want to keep the variable you have to reflash ;)